# Run command after login

Tags: login, command

I have Linux Mint 18.

How can I run this command after login with main user (no root user):

```
sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

I have read so many steps to run a command after login, but they don't work for me (or for other people too).

I need to run this command, because I run it every time to fix a network error.

Comment: XY problem - you should much rather fix the underlying problem than run this "fix" every time. Read what's stated at the top of `resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put this line in `$HOME/.bash_profile`. All commands there are run on login.

But I guess in your case it would be better to fix source of problem.
If you want to use `8.8.8.8` constantly, then you'd better add it to your network interface config.

If is usually placed in `/etc/network/interfaces`. You'll find there list of your interfaces and their configuration parameters.

Then you'll need to add line `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` to section with interface you are using.

Comment: The part about `~/.bash_profile` is not entirely correct.  It doe not run on login shells and it does not run when you enter a graphical environment (`~/.xsession` does that, but it is not respected by all graphical managers).  But yeah, adding to the interfaces is the correct path.

Comment: when i open "/etc/network/interfaces" file, no show a interface list: https://s31.postimg.org/ffz3ot29n/interfaces_etc_network_as_superuser_003.png

Comment: OMG,i can fix this!! 6 months with this problem!! every time run this command omg.I tell you what i do: i insert the command in the "rc.local" file, changing the commando to: (sleep 60 echo "my_root_password" | sudo -S echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null) & I add the password parameter because the "sudo" command, and add the sleep command, because without sleep don't work. I think that is because script was replace for network configuration generated after script run. With sleep, the script run after network system configuration is set. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Well, if this way satisfies your needs, then congratulations to you :)
With time you'll figure how things done in linux. In this particular case you can dig into setting up network connections in Ubuntu (from which Mint is derived) and maybe some tricks with `visudo` so you'll won't need your password hardcoded in plain text somewhere.
Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Add the commands to the end of your bashrc file

```
  vi ~/.bashrc
```